# "No module named 'rest_auth'" Error even though I have rest_auth installed?

Tags: django-rest-framework

"ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rest_auth'" Error even though I have rest_auth installed?

Full Error Log:

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x000001D1C08458C8>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Jeremy\Work\Coding\git\file_upload_restrict\env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 225, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Jeremy\Work\Coding\git\file_upload_restrict\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 109, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "D:\Jeremy\Work\Coding\git\file_upload_restrict\env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 248, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[1]
  File "D:\Jeremy\Work\Coding\git\file_upload_restrict\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 337, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "D:\Jeremy\Work\Coding\git\file_upload_restrict\env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 225, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Jeremy\Work\Coding\git\file_upload_restrict\env\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "D:\Jeremy\Work\Coding\git\file_upload_restrict\env\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 89, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "D:\Jeremy\Work\Coding\git\file_upload_restrict\env\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 90, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
  File "D:\Jeremy\Work\Coding\git\file_upload_restrict\env\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 965, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rest_auth'
```

I have 'django-rest-auth' installed with pip and all of these in my INSTALLED_APPS:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'rest_auth',
]
```

my pip freeze:

```
Django==2.1.4
django-appconf==1.0.2
django-cleanup==3.0.1
django-private-storage==2.1.3
django-rest-auth==0.9.3
djangorestframework==3.9.0
Pillow==5.3.0
pytz==2018.7
rcssmin==1.0.6
rjsmin==1.0.12
six==1.12.0
```

link to full code with virtual environment in gitlab.com

> https://gitlab.com/Jeremy_Munshi/file_upload_restrict

Comment: When does this error occur? I cloned the project, installed the dependencies and run `python manage.py runserver` and the server started fine

Comment: Are you using an IDE to `runserver`? It can be a possibility that your `pip freeze` is using another `virtualenv` and your `runserver` is using another one.

Comment: I'm confused, I activate environment and run `python manage.py runserver` in command prompt and everything runs fine with no errors. I do the exact same thing in PowerShell and it throws me the error I described above in my question. Why???

Comment: @HimanshuShankar Just plain old PowerShell.

Comment: @LucasWeyne When I run `python manage.py runserver` using PowerShell (Yes, proper Environment Active).

Comment: Do this @JeremyJeminMunshi 
In powershell, activate `virtualenv` and run `pip freeze` to check what's happening.
Also, I will suggest to find an equivalent of `which` command in unix to further debug.

Comment: @HimanshuShankar I already did `pip freeze` with PowerShell, the results I showed in my Question above is all done in PowerShell (Yes, with `virtualenv activated). If you have Windows 10 could you kindly clone my code in the link above (https://gitlab.com/Jeremy_Munshi/file_upload_restrict) and check if your PowerShell is also giving similar errors?

Comment: Your virtual environment was created using conda? I reproduce the error using Windows PowerShell with my `virtualenv` created by conda. I realize that PowerShell does not activate my environment at `activate myvirtualenv` (after call `pip freeze` the dependencies displayed was from my root environment, without `rest_auth`). I make a search about this and found an [issue](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/661)

Comment: @LucasWeyne Not sure what conda is but I used default Windows 10 PowerShell and after I activate my Virtual Environment (using `env\Scripts\activate`) and then run `pip freeze` I get the above results from my question which does include `django-rest-auth==0.9.3`.